# how to animate text anchor in D3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, text-alignment

I'm trying to transform a word cloud to a word list. I've managed to do but hit a problem on animating text. Because word cloud uses `text-anchor: middle` for text positioning, when I switch to list layout which uses `text-anchor: start`, words spikes a bit as animation starts. See fiddle and related code below:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QLmU/3/)

```
text.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("text-anchor", opts.textAnchor)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
     })
     .style("font-size", function(d) {
          return d.size + "px";
     })
```

I think, I should calculate each text position manually and create my own centered text instead of `text-anchor: middle`. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is indeed to center the text yourself instead of using and animating `text-anchor`. This is relatively easy, you just have to determine the width of the text and offset it by half that length to center:

```
.attr("dx", function() {
  if(opts.textAnchor == "start") {
    return 0;
  } else if(opts.textAnchor == "middle") {
    return -this.getBBox().width/2 + "px";
  }
})
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4QLmU/5/).

Comment: Your demo has the same problem as the original jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah, well spotted. I was moving around some code to tidy up... Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: couldn't also using a transition with linear easing between the middle and start text anchor make that movement a bit smoother?

Comment: Certainly possible -- feel free to play around with it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `.getBBox()` function. That made everything simple.